# In weighted least squares, can you use inverse square roots of the estimated variance instead of inverse of estimated variance?

Tags: weighted-regression

as weights?

What's the advantage or disadvantage?

Comment: Weight inversely proportional to variance minimizes the variance of the resulting estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Under assumptions of independent, normally distributed residuals, weighting at 1/variance corresponds to a maximum likelihood estimator for the model, so it's easier to justify from theory (subject to the usual quibbles about MLE).